# I am confused why I need Base64 encode after HMAC-SHA1

Tags: java, base64

if I didn't use the Base64 encoder after hmac-sha1, it would show shome unreadable code, but if I use it

Answer (score 1):

You would Base64 encode the data so that you can copy and paste the data in applications, such as an email or text file, so that people will be able to read it.

Comment: But i needn't copy it, just transfer it to another app such as a serviece app on another pc.

Comment: But how will you do that? If you use sockets or something it's fine, but as soon as a human needs to read it, it should be base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Using Base64 encode will convert your data into character values that can easily be cut-paste into emails, saved as Strings, or saved in files. If you don't use Base64 encoding, it will just be a series of byte values, which can't be copied easily and aren't displayable as characters.